# Angularjs 1.3.15 - Updating $scope after Promise Returned

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm learning angularjs and trying to update nav bar with user name after login, but the user name does not appear. Here is the process I am following:

1. User logs in successfully.
2. After 'then' in login promise (to make sure promise is returned), get user profile via factory which returns the user profile.
3. After 'success' in getting user profile, save profile to $scope.user so that DOM is updated.

Here is HTML for Nav Bar (not sure if it matters but this is placed into index.html using ng-include on page load):

```
<nav ng-controller="menuController">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            Admin Site
        </a>
    </div>
    <ul >
        <li ><span>Welcome {{ user.firstName }}</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the menuController js file:

```
    angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller("menuController", ['$scope', '$auth', '$timeout', '$window', 'toaster', 'Account',
        function UserCtrl($scope, $auth, $timeout, $window, toaster, Account) {

            $scope.user = [];

            $scope.login = function () {
                $auth.login({email: $scope.email, password: $scope.password})
                    .then(function(response){
                        toaster.pop('success', "Logged In", "You have successfully logged into the system"); // This fires correctly
                        Account.getProfile()
                            .success(function(obj){
                                $scope.user = obj;
                                console.log('User: ' + 
$scope.user.firstName);  //This Works! But user.firstName in HTML is not updated
                            });
                    })
                    .catch(function (response) {
                        toaster.pop('error', "Login Failure", response.data.message);
                    })
            };   
        }
    ]);
```

HTML from index.html

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div ng-include='"templates/navigation.html"'></div>

        <div ng-view></div>

</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->
```

The problem is that the user.firstName in the navigation bar never updates with the user's first name. Am I missing something?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I think you are missing a </nav> closing tag in your html instead of "</div>" at the end of the shown html

Comment: @Dola - updated. Error was due to copy and paste.

Comment: does `$scope.user = [];` really needed?

Comment: is there url/state redirect after login? if so, this data will gone.

Comment: @YOU - thanks. I updated the question with the basic contents of index.html as maybe that will better explain. Yes, the page redirects using ng-view away from login, but the nav is on a different controller. Other functions work in the menuController when navigating to other pages. For example, there is a logout button (removed for brevity) that calls ng-click="logout()" and it works fine.

Comment: if ng-view got rewritten, controller will start again, you can check "Preserve log" (Console tab) in chrome dev tools, and put console.log($scope.user) inside menuController, to check out how to times it gets called.

Comment: I removed the $scope.user = [] and then put console.log("Check: " + $scope.user) at the bottom of the controller. When the page first loads (before I log in), there are two 'Check: undefined', but after I log in it does not update the console again. I even took the redirect out of the router and just have it stay on the log in page. I checked the network tab in dev tools and there is no other files being sent or received...

Answer (score 0):

What does `Account.getProfile()` return? Is it angular promise or something outside angular framework? 
Perhaps you should wrap the code inside `$apply` scope:

```
Account.getProfile()
    .success(function(obj){
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.user = obj;
            console.log('User: ' + 
            $scope.user.firstName);  //This Works! But user.firstName in HTML is not updated
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and unfortunately it did not work. I suspect that @YOU is correct that data is lost on redirect (though I can't seem to prove it using console.log)...